# Navigate Python Script in IDLE without Arrow Keys

Tags: python, python-idle

Similar to Emacs C-f, C-b, C-p, C-n, is there a way to navigate a .py script in IDLE without using the arrow keys? When I go to configure IDLE I don't see any key bindings for this.

*Please don't just leave a smug comment such as 'Why are you using IDLE in the first place?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure IDLE this way:

1. Open up the menu item Options -> Configure IDLE...
2. Go to Keys tab
3. In the drop down menu on the right side of the dialog change the select to "IDLE Classic Unix"